# what is the purpose of an ajax submit with leading hash characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I'm observing ajax submit via console and I'm wondering when the site requests or pulls somethings via ajax it processes it on a js with leading hash character.

application-**74fe7540bbc2a304e421e68726a13599**.js

Would anybody know the purpose of this?

Comment: It probaly saves it that way in cache. A browser caches everything, and you can't cache stuff when you have name conflicts, and since json requests are "anomynous application requests" they get a random name. But, that's only my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will prevent the browsers to cache the contents of such file. Can't say for sure, but I think that inside this file your application has a specific data, a new one each time, or may be this hash is included in `validation-of-requests` logic on the server side.